duplicate `rel` attribute emitted by Perl 5.18.2's CGI `start_html`
In a program I'm using a rather sophisticated parameter for CGI's start_html, but that results in a duplicate rel attribute for the CSS passed via -style.
Example code:
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $attr = {
    '-script' => [
        {
            '-src' => 'https://server.domain.org/app/js/0.js',
            '-type' => 'text/javascript'
        },
        {
            '-src' => 'https://server.domain.org/app/js/2.js',
            '-type' => 'text/javascript'
        },
        {
            '-type' => 'text/javascript',
            '-src' => 'https://server.domain.org/app/js/3.js'
        }
    ],
    '-noscript' => '<link type="text/css" href="https://server.domain.org/app/style/3.css" id="3.css" title="No Script Additions" rel="stylesheet" />',
    '-encoding' => 'utf-8',
    '-author' => 'Me &lt;my@e.mail&gt;',
    '-lang' => 'de-DE',
    '-style' => [
        {
            '-id' => '2.css',
            '-type' => 'text/css',
            '-src' => 'https://server.domain.org/app/style/2.css',
            '-rel' => 'stylesheet alternate',
            '-title' => 'JavaScript Additions'
        }
    ],
    '-meta' => {
            'copyright' => 'Copyright ...',
            'keywords' => 'bla',
            'description' => 'Application to ...'
    },
    '-title' => '[ldapdir-3.8] Login'
};
my $query = CGI->new;

print $query->start_html($attr), "\n";

Output:
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="de-DE" xml:lang="de-DE">
<head>
<title>[ldapdir-3.8] Login</title>
<link rev="made" href="mailto:Me%20%26lt%3Bmy%40e.mail%26gt%3B" />
<meta name="copyright" content="Copyright ..." />
<meta name="description" content="Application to ..." />
<meta name="keywords" content="bla" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://server.domain.org/app/style/2.css" id="2.css" rel="stylesheet alternate" title="JavaScript Additions"/>
<script src="https://server.domain.org/app/js/0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://server.domain.org/app/js/2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://server.domain.org/app/js/3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<noscript>
<link type="text/css" href="https://server.domain.org/app/style/3.css" id="3.css" title="No Script Additions" rel="stylesheet" />
</noscript>

</head>
<body>

I tend to believe it's a bug in $CGI::VERSION='3.63'.
How can I fix it?

By defining -style on top level of the %attr array you already defined the "stylesheet". You do not need to define -rel manually.

So is the solution to use -link instead of -style?

The CGI module has been removed from core for being obsolete (the author's own words in the docs), and the HTML generation functions are no longer maintained, as described here: https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used

@ikegami So you are saying -style is just an alias for -link having pre-set '-rel' => 'stylesheet'?

@TLP I agree that CGI's HTML generation is primitive and not perfect, but people have built around those, so simply dropping it is a no-go IMHO. I'd probably build my own mostly compatible version of CGI then. That way you can rely on its existence in the future.

I tried to change $attr to create a correct link, but either I got nothing or just <body link="ARRAY(0x5636c5a95fc8)"> for '-Link' => [ '<link ...>' ] (in addition to the rest). Before I had tried a hash ref instead of the scalar, but that won't work either. I even tried to understand the source of CGI.pm for two hours or so...

@U.Windl I used CGI myself for a large-ish project about 20 years ago, and found it awkward to use even then. I found myself avoiding CGI's own functions whenever I could. I've never used any other module for it, but I can believe what they say when they say it's the wrong way to go. Investing some time to learn a newer and better module might be time well spent.

I haven't voted, but I suspect the votes are because you are using CGI to make HTML.

With the same argument one could down-vote any question related to using C... - I mean it's OK to say CGI is not well-designed, and it's considered to be obsolete, and that many don't use it, etc., but down-voting just because you don't know or like the subject is a no-go IMHO.

After reading LIMITED SUPPORT FOR CASCADING STYLE SHEETS I changed the attributes like this (so I dropped -rel and -type while adding '-alternate' => 1):
# ...
    '-style' => [
        {
            '-id' => '2.css',
            '-alternate' => 1,
            '-src' => 'https://server.domain.org/app/style/2.css',
            '-title' => 'JavaScript Additions'
        }
    ],
# ...

and the resulting HTML was
<!-- ... -->
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://server.domain.org/app/style/2.css" title="JavaScript Additions" id="2.css"/>
<!-- ... -->

and the duplicate rel was gone.
